# PHP & MySql match a Word/Phrase in a String

Tags: php, mysql, string, search

i have a Table in MySql with Cities.

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|          ID         |     City         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |     Berlin       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |     Los Angeles  |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |     Shanghai     |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

and i have a String in Php like this: 
$string = "I like Berlin and Los Angeles."

Now i want look in the MySql-Database if the String contains a City/Cities.
But i dont know what is the best solution. Maybe its better or/and faster to have the List with Cities as Json File?

Comment: Take a array from your database , meanwhile explode your string sentence may be by `" "` , put them in a loop & check if you find any words in common .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You an use mysql query for checking it.

```
Select * from table_name where match(City) against ('I like Berlin and Los Angeles')
```

or you can use like

```
Select * from table_name where city like '%I like Berlin and Los Angeles%'
```

I am modified the query as you need the sort mechanism in it.

```
Select *,(match(City) against ('I like Los Angeles  and Berlin')) as relevance  from city 
where match(City) against ('I like Los Angeles and  Berlin') ORDER BY relevance ASC;
```

It would give you sort on city present in table.

Comment: the column which we want to use match function must be a FULLTEXT index

Comment: @Nishtant Your second answer ist interesting! I never had the idea to check the complete String as a like function! And the City-Field must be a FULLTEXT index?

Comment: The "against" method is working fine but one little problem. how can i get the results in the order, how it is in the string?
in my example it should be 1. berlin und 2. los angeles.

Comment: @Dennis I have modified the query and tried on my console too. Its working and request you to have a `Full text Index` on city column. it helps  for searching faster result.

Comment: @Nishtant First, thanks for your great help! What i exactly need is, that the results of the mysql should be in sort how the the cities are in the string. "I like Berlin and Los Angeles" >> the result must be 1. berlin and 2. los angeles. the background is, i m working on a flight search and the the first city is the destination and the second the origin. is this possible with mysql?

Comment: @Dennis have you tried out the query it gives the same result which you need. You can also apply weight to your relevance.

Answer (score 0):

You should take all cities from database to an array then checking it.

```
$cities = ['Berlin', 'Los Angeles', 'Shanghai'];
$string = 'I like Berlin and Los Angeles.';
$result = [];
$pattern = '/('.implode('|', $cities).')/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $result);
```

SAMPLE: http://phpio.net/s/2t70

Comment: That works nice! How can i do this with a multidimensional array?